# Templates as content

Tags: 8, theming

I currently have a project with the requirement to edit templates for content like content, i.e. we will have a template content type which will be used as template for another content type.

I've looked for projects and best practices on the matter but didn't find anything. Does someone have experiences with a similar setup?

Should I use Twig and inline_template or should I write my own template system with tokens? Other ideas?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I advise scrapping this entire idea and just install Paragraphs or Panels. Don't malign a content type into being a layout object... you'll wind up with a mess in the end. Stick to good models, relations, structured fields and unstructured when needed (Paragraphs/Panels).

Comment: I foresee a lot of content types in your future. I've seen this before, and it ends up being a mess when you pair it with configuration/features. Don't do it. Figure out what the real requirement is and work from there. I think what Kevin suggested is correct - it seems like the real requirement is to be able to let content creators create dynamic content layouts and this can be done with layout builder/panels

Comment: Or yes, wait until 8.7.0 is relesaed with Layout Builder, or check out Acquia Lightning 4.0.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the use case. In fact the client will even need js and css per template, Paragraphs or Layout Builder will not do the job here. I agree that the setup is not optimal, but it's a set requirement unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what the client really wants is something like the Paragraphs module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs

It's a good solution for creating flexible, yet structured, content.

Take a look at this video for a good idea of the promises (and pitfalls) of this approach:

https://www.oomphinc.com/notes/2018/11/component-based-design-system-drupal-8-paragraphs/